# 05 jeep wrangler rear sway bar connection is broken

Tags: suspension, jeep

05 jeep wrangler .The link that connects my rear sway bar to the rear end housing. What's it called. where can I buy a replacement. To be welded or fit in.

Comment: Can you present a picture of what's broken? Would help us provide an answer for you.

Comment: I downvoted because this question shows basically no effort on the part of the asker.  I also answered because they asked for help and that's what we're about.

Answer (score 2):

Um...

Here's the [Duralast Rear Sway Bar Link](http://www.autozone.com/parts/suspension-steering-tire-and-wheel/sway-bar-link/duralast-sway-bar-link/jeep/wrangler-4wd/2005/6-cylinders-s-4-0l-sfi/761248_0_0_4145/) for your vehicle on AutoZone.com.  Part number `EL159`.  It's just called a `sway bar link` and in the description it specifies front or rear.

It's the same part whether you have the 4 cylinder or the 6.

On RockAuto.com, it's called a [Stabilizer Bar Link](http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/raframecatalog.php?carcode=1430906&parttype=7580) and in the description it specifies front or rear.

Answer (score 1):

Check with your local off-road or Jeep club, if there's one in your area, chances are someone has some sitting in the garage. Many people who off-road remove the rear sway bar completely. If you're driving on the road, and haven't made any other provisions, I wouldn't recommend doing this, but you might find someone willing to give you a sway bar link.